# Spark not booting up form home directory

Tags: apache-spark

I installed spark on my home directory and gave the path in the bash file. Now Spark doesn't fire up when being called using "Spark-shell"

**bashrc**:

```
export SCALA_HOME=/home/spark/scala-2.12.1
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export SPARK_HOME=/home/spark/spark/
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

**error**:

> spark@sE3:~/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin$ ./spark-shell
>   ./spark-shell: line 57: /home/spark/spark//bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory

Comment: Error Thrown: spark@sE3:~/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin$ ./spark-shell
./spark-shell: line 57: /home/spark/spark//bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls verify the `/home/spark/spark/bin/` is right folder or not. since `spark/spark/` is 2 times

Also cross check with below..

```
readlink -f spark-submit
```

will give you correct sparkhome if you have symlinks,

you can also use

```
SPARK_HOME="$(cd "`dirname $(readlink -nf "$0")`"/.. ; pwd -P)"
```